# How to check if a crate on solana and anchor repo can be used on-chain or off-chain?

Tags: solana-program, build-sbf

This question has hanging over my head for long time.

How to tell a crate provided by solana org or third party can be imported and use from on-chain code? Is there any flag in cargo.toml file to tell from?

For example, I once try to use the hash function from `anchor-syn` crate, but it failed to compile. (See [this post](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/12195/how-to-use-sighash-function-from-anchor-syn-crate-in-my-on-chain-code))
So I draw a conclusion that `anchor-syn` crate is not compile for `sbf-solana-solana` target.  But it is just my own guest, and unable to justify this.

Another related question, how to set target_os for IDE to high-light the solana code correctly. For example, the vscode in my side obvious not high light the solana code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to easily tell if a crate is usable on-chain unfortunately. You can look through the crate's code and dependencies for things that *aren't* possible, like `rand` or `net`, but past that, it isn't easy.

To be honest, your best bet is to import it, try to use it, and see if the compiler reports an error.

As for your VSCode issue, that might belong in a separate question :-)